# Expose added public method in AWS lambda project as api

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I am working on a AWS amplify application and I have an existing AWS API gateway(payments api, payments path) which points to a .Net lambda function(payments namespace, payments class, createPaymentIntent method name).

a. If I edit the .Net lambda function's payments class to add another public method, how do I expose it as an api? 
b. Similarly if I add another class(charges?) and a public method(ListAllCharges) to the .Net lambda function project, how do I expose it as an api?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Referring to your API Gateway config screenshot, since you are using a Lambda proxy integration, the [API Gateway proxy event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html) includes a `path` parameter which can be used to determine the API path to which the request was made.

Now, you can use the same Lambda function as the integration  for different API Gateway resources. The point to note here is that the same Lambda handler function will be invoked from API Gateway. You would have to include logic in the handler to determine the API path from the API GW event received and then accordingly invoke the required method in your function to return the result.